# Bind Variables in order by in OracleSql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, mulesoft

I have requirement to have different order by criteria that will be set by user from **UI**. e.g. it can be

`order by a asc, b desc, c asc , d asc`

or

`order by b asc, a desc, c desc , d desc`

It can be any combination that I will make from **UI**. How can I pass this to order by in **OracleSql** using **Bind Variables** in **mulesoft 3.9**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column data types are compatible you can do something like this and repeat for as many sort options as needed, if the data types aren't compatible, split the case statements up to have one pair (asc,desc) for each group of compatible data types:

```
select * from your_table
 order by case case :col_1_dir when 'desc' then null else :col_1 end
             when 'a' then a
             when 'b' then b
             when 'c' then c
             when 'd' then d
             else null
          end
        , case case :col_1_dir when 'asc' then null else :col_1 end
             when 'a' then a
             when 'b' then b
             when 'c' then c
             when 'd' then d
             else null
          end desc
        , case case :col_2_dir when 'desc' then null else :col_2 end
             when 'a' then a
             when 'b' then b
             when 'c' then c
             when 'd' then d
             else null
          end
        , case case :col_2_dir when 'asc' then null else :col_2 end
             when 'a' then a
             when 'b' then b
             when 'c' then c
             when 'd' then d
             else null
          end desc
```

Comment: I tried the same way but then the data was not been bound properly

Answer (score 0):

You can't use bind variables to specify column names.  Bind variables only pass values.

Comment: is there any other option to specify custom column names and order by

Comment: No, because you can't dynamically build statements.  SQL has to know everything about the columns and how the query will work, and it does that before it executes.  It has to make a plan.  Bind variables work at execution time.